# How get stringValue from FeedItem[] item

Tags: c#, google-ads-api

I'm downloading some data from google adWords
My code looks like this :

> ```
>     public static FeedItem[] GetFeedItems(string _cid)
>     {
>         var user = CurrentOAuthUser.ConfigureUserForOAuthInstance(_cid).GetCurrentUser();
>         FeedItemService feedItemService = (FeedItemService)user.GetService(
>             AdWordsService.v201502.FeedItemService);
>         FeedItemPage page = feedItemService.query(string.Format("Select FeedItemId, " +
>             "AttributeValues, Scheduling where PlaceholderType = 1"));
>         return page.entries;
>     }
> ```

my result looks like this: [image]

Now i need to get the information that in blue , the string value of this object.
I tried this with foreach but had no success. 
Do anyone have any idea how gen I get this value ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach(var attribute in resultList)
 foreach(var val in attribute.attributeValues)
  foreach(string x in val.stringvalues)
   Console.Write(x)
```

Comment: im starting with "resultList" it looks like this:  var resultList = GetReport.GetFeedItems("12345678"); from where im getting the "attributeValues" ? var

Comment: @user2450821then just add another foreach on the top of the one's above to iterate through all items of the resultList

Comment: it dosent know what is the "attributeValues" means I did it like this       foreach (var attribute in resultList)
            {
                foreach (var val in attribute)
                {
                    foreach(string x in string values)
                }
                
            } but its is wrong !

Comment: the type is not enumerable

Comment: still wrong :( "cannot resolve symbol "stringvalues" error

Comment: @user2450821 just change it to stringValues (that's the name of the property n your class)

Comment: @user2450821 make sure you vote my answer, glad I helped!

Comment: ooo it still not working cause the first string value is null so i'm getting null exception

Comment: @user2450821 then just do a nullity check